# IE throws 'Unspecified error' when reloading a page with swfobject embedded on it

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, swfobject

I have a simple page with an swfobject embedded on it.
Looks like IE has problems with the 'filters' property on the embedded object.
My test page looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "";
        $(function()
        {
            var flashvars = {};
            var parameters = {};
            var attributes = {};
            flashvars["data-file"] = url;
            parameters.wmode = "transparent";       
            swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "graph1", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, parameters, attributes);
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #graph1
        {
            margin:30px;
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graph1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**note:** the `test.swf` file is the one swfobject package from the [download page](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/list).

now when i reload the page, it throws an 'Unspecified error' on IE, but not on firefox in which the filters property is set to `undefined`.

the code that seems to cause the error is in swfobject.js v2.2 (lines 494-504):

```
/*! SWFObject v2.2 <http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/> 
    is released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/


function removeObjectInIE(id) {
        var obj = getElementById(id);
        if (obj) {
            for (var i in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[i] == "function") {
                    obj[i] = null; // when (i == 'filters') we get the error
                }
            }
            obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Two things that immediately caught my eye:

First:
You wrapped your anonymous function (containing the SWFObject code) in a jQuery 'dollar' declaration.  The jQuery dollar function "accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a set of elements."

Your function doesn't return anything, so it will cause a JavaScript error when jQuery tries to use a null reference as a CSS selector. `swfobject.embedSWF` does not return a value, either, so it would probably be best to drop the jQuery dollar function from your code.

If you just wanted your code to run in an anonymous function, drop the `$` and add a function invocation at the end:

```
(function()
    {
        var flashvars = {};
        var parameters = {};
        var attributes = {};
        flashvars["data-file"] = url;
        parameters.wmode = "transparent";       
        swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "graph1", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, parameters, attributes);
})();
```

Second:
You're passing a FlashVars variable name that contains a hyphen, which is illegal in both JavaScript and ActionScript.

Lastly, `removeObjectInIE` (a subfunction of `swfobject.removeSWF`) has been thoroughly tested in IE 6, 7, and 8.  Since IE9 is still in beta, swfobject doesn't officially support it yet. However, we don't anticipate any issues. I suggest trying the edits I mention above and see if it clears up your issue.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will check if removing the dollar sign works and let you know. please note that this page is just a simple test page i created while trying to hunt down the source of that mysterious bug. on my main site the embedding doesn't occur within the docReady method, which makes me think its not the cause of the problem. as for the illegal hyphen, it is required by the component we are using, open-flash-chart, which also makes me think it shouldn't cause the browser to set the filters prop to an exception. once again, thanks, i will get back with answers soon.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how you have your page set up, but just FYI swfobject.embedSWF has an automatic 'domready' function, so you don't need to use jQuery's $(document).ready.  Using jQuery's $(document).ready with swfobject.embedSWF won't cause any errors, but it would be redundant.

Comment: +1 The function invocation and not always wrapping a function in the 'dollar' are great tips

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea, why this happens, but you could try to fix it with a try/catch

```
try{obj[i] = null;}catch(e){}
```

This should avoid error messages.

Comment: my current solution is in the same direction.  I don't like it. thanks anyway :)